# The values of constants in the Equation.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \frac{\int_0^{4\pi} e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}{\int_0^\pi e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}= L, $$
the question asks the value of $a$ and $L$.
My friend solved it by differentiating, but i didn't understood a single thing. May be it is a very simple one, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you using capital $L$ and lower-case $l$ to refer to the same thing?  Generally one should not do that. $\qquad$

Comment: Are you asking for $a$ as a function of $L$? $\qquad$

Comment: No, because L will have only a single value.

Comment: I've used mathematica to check the value of $L$, but it is a function of $a$ and not a finite number!!

Comment: ok, can you solve it for values of a=2,4 @Jan Eerland 9

Comment: When we put $a=2$ in the sin term and $a=4$ in the cosine term we get $\text{L}=\left(1+e^{\pi}\right)\left(1+e^{2\pi}\right)$

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the numerator can be written as
$$\int_{0}^{4\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt+\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt+\int_{3\pi}^{4\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt$$

Now substitute $t=k+\pi$ in the second integral on the R.H.S, to get $$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{k+\pi}(\sin^{6}ak+\cos^{4}ak)dk$$
because $\sin^6ak=\sin^6(ak+\pi)$ and same for $\cos^4ak$
$$=e^\pi \times \int_{0}^{\pi}e^k(\sin^{6}ak+\cos^{4}ak)dk$$
Similarly for the other two integrals substitute $t=k+2\pi$ and $t=k+3\pi$ to get 
$$\frac{\int_{0}^{4\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt}{\int_{0}^{\pi}e^t(\sin^{6}at+\cos^{4}at)dt}=1+e^\pi+e^{2\pi}+e^{3\pi}$$
$$=\color{red} {\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^\pi-1}}$$

**Why the particular substitutions?**

> These are done in order to make the limits of the integrals present in the  numerators and denominators the same while also keeping in mind the periodicity of the trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

> Use, one of the properties of the intergal:
>
> $$\int\left[f(x)+g(x)\right]\space\text{d}x=\int f(x)\space\text{d}x+\int g(x)\space\text{d}x$$

So, we get that:

$$\int e^t\left(\sin^6(at)+\cos^4(at)\right)\space\text{d}t=\int e^t\sin^6(at)\space\text{d}t+\int e^t\cos^4(at)\space\text{d}t$$

Now, for $\int e^t\sin^6(at)\space\text{d}t$ use the reduction formula:

$$\int e^{at}\sin^n(bt)\space\text{d}t=\frac{e^{at}\sin^{n-1}(bt)(a\sin(bt)-bn\cos(bt))}{a^2+b^2n^2}+\frac{b^2(n-1)n\int e^{at}\sin^{n-2}bt)\space\text{d}t}{a^2+b^2n^2}$$

Use the trigonometric identity:

$$\sin^2(at)=\frac{1-\cos(2at)}{2}$$

Now, for $\int e^t\cos^4(at)\space\text{d}t$ use the reduction formula:

$$\int e^{at}\cos^n(bt)\space\text{d}t=\frac{bn\sin(bt)+a\cos(bt)}{a^2+b^2n^2}+\frac{b^2(n-1)n\int e^{at}\cos^{n-2}(bt)\space\text{d}t}{a^2+b^2n^2}$$

Use the trigonometric identity:

$$\cos^2(at)=\frac{1+\cos(2at)}{2}$$

Comment: I am not known to Reduction formula, can you suggest more simpler approach.

Comment: Actually, you can find the reduction formula's by yourself! Use your integration skills, it is not as easy as it seems!

Answer (score -1):

We have$$\frac{\int_0^{4\pi} e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}{\int_0^\pi e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}= F(a)$$ It follows the equation $$F(a)=L$$
The calculation made by Nikunj makes us see that $F$ is independent of $a$.

Thus the answer is $a$  arbitrary and $L={\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^\pi-1}}\approx 12.9512$

Comment: Happy? It is regrettable that someone without mathematical maturity can put a downvote.